# Recorrer lista de objetos en JSON

Tags: jquery, json, api

Tengo este JSON

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0025,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
        "dt": 1503586800,
            "main": {
                "temp": 307.92,
                "temp_min": 307.92,
                "temp_max": 308.292,
                "pressure": 956.05,
                "sea_level": 1026.51,
                "grnd_level": 956.05,
                "humidity": 19,
                "temp_kf": -0.37
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 6.57,
                "deg": 232.003
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2017-08-24 15:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1503597600,
            "main": {
                "temp": 305.14,
                "temp_min": 305.14,
                "temp_max": 305.416,
                "pressure": 956.03,
                "sea_level": 1026.69,
                "grnd_level": 956.03,
                "humidity": 17,
                "temp_kf": -0.28
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5.57,
                "deg": 246
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2017-08-24 18:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "city": {
        "id": 3117735,
        "name": "Madrid",
        "coord": {
            "lat": 40.4165,
            "lon": -3.7026
        },
        "country": "ES"
    }
}
```

He conseguido mostrar la ciudad (city.name), y las coordenadas (city.coord). Pero quisiera mostrar el atributo list.weather.main. El cual creo que se encuentra dentro de una lista de objetos. No se como recorrerlo. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
$.each( data.city, function( key, val ) {
    if (key=="name"){
        items.push("Ciudad: "+val);
    }
});

$.each( data.city, function( key, val ) {
    if (key=="coord"){
        items.push(" Coordenadas: "+val.lat);
    }
});
```

Y para intentar mostrar la lista de objetos, hago lo siguiente:

```
$.each( data.list, function( key, val ) {
    if (key=="weather"){
        items.push(" Coordenadas: "+val.main);
    }
});
```

Pero no funciona, alguna ayudita?

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio ^^ puedes explicar mejor por que no funciona? has hecho logs para ver que esta sucediendo? errores por consola te muestra? Para mas informacion , tienes [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Los datos de ejemplo son demasiados, por favor solo incluye un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 1):

Primero tenes que acceder a la propiedad "list" mediante la notación objeto.propiedad para recorrerla con el bucle `$.each`

```
data.list
// Devuelve un arreglo que contiene objetos [{ .. }, { .. }, { .. }]
```

Podes acceder a la propiedad "weather" de cada elemento que se encuentre en list usando el punto, de esta forma:

```
value.weather
// Devuelve un arreglo que contiene un solo objeto [{ .. }]
```

Como weather almacena un arreglo, tenes que usar el índice 0 para acceder a él y nuevamente la notación de punto.

```
value.weather[0].main
// Devuelve la cadena "Clear"
```

Todo junto quedaría así:

```
$.each( data.list, function (i, value) {
    items.push( value.weather[0].main );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que `list` no tiene propiedades, sino que tiene **índices**. Primero tienes que recorrer las posiciones antes de entrar a sus propiedades, por ejemplo:

```
$.each(data.list, function( oKey, oVal ) { //outter Key, outter Val
    $.each(data.list[oKey], function( key, val){ 
        if (key=="weather"){
            items.push(" Coordenadas: "+val.main);
        }
    });
});
```

Sin embargo, dentro de `weather` **también tienes un arreglo** con índices, por lo tanto también debes acceder a cada posición (que solo es una). Si el arreglo `weather` permanecerá así, con solo una posición, no debería ser difícil:

```
$.each(data.list, function( oKey, oVal ) { //outter Key, outter Val
    $.each(data.list[oKey], function( key, val ){ 
        if (key=="weather"){
            items.push(" Coordenadas: " + val[0].main);
        }
    });
});
```

Lo que resultaría en:

```
items = [" Coordenadas: Clear"," Coordenadas: Clear", ...]
```

De no ser así, necesitarías una iteración adicional.